# A text appears two times puppeteer

Tags: javascript, text, puppeteer

Hello so I have a text `test123test345` and I extract it with the following commands

```js
const element = await this.page.$('[id="testdata"]');
const text = await (await element.getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();
```

Then I tried to do the following:

```js
expect(text).toContain('test');
```

But I want to expect that the test appears two times. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be more solutions, one could be this:

```js
import chai from 'chai';
const expect = chai.expect;
expect(text).to.match(/(test.*){2}/);
```

- to quickly try regex, you can go to https://regexr.com/
- `match()` is explained here: https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_match

Comment: I receive this error:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'expect' of undefined

Comment: If you just copy & paste it, it probably won't work. It at least requires chai library as I show in the example and `text` variable which I took from your example.

Comment: do you have another example instead of /(test123){2}/ ? this construction doesn't seem to work

Comment: I made a mistake in the regex, if you want to macth 'test' twice, `/(test.*){2}/` should do.

Answer (score 0):

so with help from @pavelsaman this works for me:
I run `npm install chai` then the following code:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
expect(text).to.match(/(test.*){2}/);
```

`